# react testing library - findByText() to be not .inTheDocument()

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Trying to write a negative case for a unit test;

When i have a component that is waiting on a promise to be fulfilled, how do i test that it's not in the document?

e.g.

```js
import {screen} from '@testing-library/react'


describe('<TodoAsync>', () => {
    it("should show when when it's loading", async () => {
      expect(await screen.findByText(<TodoAsync  />)).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `TodoAsync` component?